# How can I get count of total order weekly between two dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to get count of total orders weekly between two dates in SQL, Firebird. For instance, let's say start date is  '2019-09-18' and end date is '2019-12-01'. I want to get the total number of orders for each week between these two dates and the first day of this week.

I tried something like this but it is wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), dat FROM RB r 
WHERE TARIH BETWEEN '2019-09-18' AND '2019-12-01'
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 7, '2019-09-18') AS dat;
```

Also, I couldn't even get weeks in Firebird:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ww ,date '2019-09-18' , date '2019-12-01');
```

> SQL Error [335544634] [42000]: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 1, column 17; ww [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634]

Comment: You should consult the documentation of [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-datediff), then you'd notice the Firebird doesn't have a `ww` option, it has `week`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem like this:

```
SELECT     count(*),extract (week from r.TARIH), min( r.TARIH)
FROM        RB r 
WHERE r.TARIH BETWEEN  date '2019-09-18' AND date '2019-12-01'
GROUP BY extract (week from r.TARIH);
```

Comment: to simplify you could use     GROUP BY 2

Comment: You should really use date literals (e.g. `date '2019-09-18'`)